# How would one go about load testing a server an iOS app consumes?

Tags: iphone, ios, testing, load

For example let's say someone made an MMO.  How would they test that their server can handle the load from iOS gamers?  With the Apple's ad hoc distribution program only allowing 100 distributions I don't see how this would be done.

Comment: Did you get what you were looking for here?

Answer (score 4):

You wouldn't have to drive the load from the actual devices.  For load testing, you can create a test harness that drives load on your server (whether it's sockets, http etc...).  It just needs to drive load while you monitor performance characteristics (live counters) and find the first bottleneck and fix it.  Repeat.

Approach and tools listed here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing